# With Bootstrap, how do I show radio inputs as buttons?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, radio-group

My form currently contains this code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="opt-0"><input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt-0" checked>Option 0</label>
<label for="opt-1"><input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt-1">Option 1</label>
<label for="opt-2"><input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt-2">Option 2</label>
```

Instead of showing the radio buttons as radio buttons, I'd like to make them look like regular buttons, like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Option 0</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Option 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-default">Option 2</button>
```

I have radios and I want to make them look like toggleable buttons. How am I supposed to do that with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This save my day!!!! - replace the old <button> tag in the button group and work perfectly!

Comment: @Shibu Thomas, Is it possible to show dropdown sub menu in bootstrap 3?

Comment: @Keynes You can refer this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Comment: @ShibuThomas - thanks, it looks nice. In this implementation there's no indication on the selected option. Do you know how to add it?

Comment: How can we make an option look selected when the form loads? You can do checked="true" - but there's no visual indication it's selected?!

Comment: @Avision Add the 'active' class to the label of the button you want to be selected

Comment: I find the glow around the selected button not visible enough. Has anybody seen an elegant way of solving this?

Comment: But this is not ARIA compliant

Answer (score 38):

Bootstrap 4 now offers a [toggleable button group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) that manages the active state for you on click.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to use bootstrap validation on grouped buttons ? : ```<div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom file feedback</div>```
I'm not able to display the error message, on submit, when the input is required. I think because of the wrapped input in label tag. Otherwise, an idea about that ?

Comment: People trying to use this with a vue.js v-model, `data-toggle="buttons"` breaks the binding for me.

Comment: This is the best answer.  I set the label class to `btn btn-outline-primary` and that works super well.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/fexve4md/)
[getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at button groups, this is a goup of - well- buttons... which is toggleable like a radiobutton.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cbLoecg0/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Right</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This could work, but: 1. if I click on a button, it does not remain selected; 2. there are no `<input>` elements and I can't submit the form

Comment: Looked good, until I tried it. The buttons do not stay "toggled", so not what the OP (or me) wants